# Put a tab form inside a tab form Access 2007

Tags: forms, tabs, ms-access-2007

Is there a way that I can put a tab form inside another tab form.

I want to create a horizontal structure like :

1.

1.1

1.2

2.

2.1

2.2 
etc.

I tried putting the tab in a tab, but somehow the 'above' tab form stays on top of the 'beneath' tab form. Even when I go to the second tab page on the 'beneath' tab form.

Also tried cutting a new tab form and pasting it inside the active 'beneath' tab form.

Comment: Yes, a subform: http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/199835-tab-control-within-another-tab-control